# OOP Basics - generating a random q&a

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop, object

I'm trying to create a function that creates a random security question for form validation purposes. I'm struggling though, as I can't seem to access the final values of the variables. Any help other than php.net would be appreciated, I've been there but I don't 100% understand how to create my first object.

```
class question {

public $sq = '';
public $answer = '';

function generate_question() {

    $questions = array( array( question => "What color is the sky?",
                                answer => "blue"),
                        array(question => "What month is after April?",
                                answer => "May"),
                        array(question => "What animal is usually chasen by a cat?",
                                answer => "mouse"),
                        array(question => "What color is banana?",
                                answer => "yellow"),
                        array(question => "What is a next day after Monday?",
                                answer => "Tuesday"),
                        );

    $question = array_rand($questions);

    return $sq = $questions[$question]['question'];
    return $answer = $questions[$question]['answer'];
        }

}
$sqo = new question();

echo $sqo->sq . $sqo->answer;
```

Comment: return array with pair question-answer, also after instantiated object you can access the method, not its properties, if you need to access the properties, you need to presave them with constructor and $this->property, because using $var in method does not use the public $var in the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method can return only one value the other return won't be reached.

Change this code

```
$question = array_rand($questions);

return $sq = $questions[$question]['question'];
return $answer = $questions[$question]['answer'];
```

To

```
$question = array_rand($questions);
return $questions[$question];
```

and it will work.

To access the return array use

```
echo $sqo->answer['question'];
echo $sqo->answer['answer'];
```

The good practice is to us methods to access the class variables. These variables should be declared as private and method accessing them should be public. Also you should declare the array with questions answers as private object variable. There is no need to declare it every time when method is invoked.

I've redesigned your class to better(not the best) solution.

```
class Question
{

    private $questions;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->questions = array( array( question => "What color is the sky?",
                            answer => "blue"),
                    array(question => "What month is after April?",
                            answer => "May"),
                    array(question => "What animal is usually chasen by a cat?",
                            answer => "mouse"),
                    array(question => "What color is banana?",
                            answer => "yellow"),
                    array(question => "What is a next day after Monday?",
                            answer => "Tuesday")
                    );
    }

    public function generate_question()
    {
        return $this->questions[rand(0, count($this->questions)-1)];
    }

}

$sqo = new Question();

$question = $sqo->generate_question();
echo $question['question'];
echo $question['answer'];
```

**EDITED & WORKING**

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your reply. There was a missing closing bracket in the return line. It works after fixing though. Thanks a lot mate

Comment: actually, after few tests it turns out that the function gives some empty results once every few times ... why is that and what can you do to fix it?

Comment: My mistake it should be `count($this->questions)-1` I will edit